# MobileFirst 7.1 Encrypted Cache ERROR_COULD_NOT_GENERATE_KEY

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

my test Android device is :

1. Genymotion Custom Phone 5.1.0
2. HTC M9 5.0.2

MobileFirst platform : 7.1.0 2015-1214

when I try to use Encrypted Cache API by using this code :

```
WL.EncryptedCache.open("UserInfo", true, 
function(res){console.log("success !!");}, 
function(res){console.log("errorCode : " + JSON.stringify(res));});
```

Then I got error call back

> errorCode : 11

This errorCode should be WL.EncryptedCache.ERROR_COULD_NOT_GENERATE_KEY.

but this code works fine in iOS Device.

I can't find any info about this error code in [Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.EncryptedCache.html)

What's wrong with Encrypted Cache API or Android Device?

Comment: Does it work in stock Android devices as opposites to genymotion?

Comment: Hi Idan,  I test on real device HTC M9 (5.0.2) still got this error

Comment: I try this sample code , but same result. https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/data/storing-sensitive-data-in-encrypted-cache/#create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your application's wlclient.properties file (located in the native\assets folder).

Most likely this happens because the **host** value is set to your computer name instead of to a hostname or IP address. Change the value accordingly and this will work.

Comment: Does it Encrypted Cache API need to connect WL Server? If it does why iOS can work even when offline?

Comment: By default it will connect to the server to create a stronger encryption, but you can choose to use the device instead (less strong). The fact in iOS it works, has got nothing to do with this problem. The problem is the hostname.

Comment: How to "choose to use the device instead" (Android)? Thanks Idan

Comment: Got confused with another feature. For this feature, a server connection is required as stated in the documentation: "The process of creating a cache involves obtaining a random number from the Worklight® Server. Hence, the action of creating a cache requires that the app is connected to the Worklight Server. After a cache is created, it can then be opened without a connection."